ETIMEDOUT in Nest.JS application with nest-sftp
I'm developing a NEST.JS api (BullMQ, nest-sftp) and I have the following functionality :

Every day at 9:30 a Job needs to run that picks up a file in a folder converts it
After converting it should upload the processed file to a FTP server (SFTP)

This is done in the following way:

Creating a BullMQ & nest-schedule Producer to trigger the action


@Cron("0 30 09 * * *", { timeZone: "Europe/Brussels" })
async runInventoryUpdate(): Promise<Bull.Job> {
    return await this.inventoryQueue.add(IJobType.DAILY_DROPSHIPPING_UPDATE, {}, { removeOnFail: true });
}



The consumer picks up the trigger and processes


async jlineDSU() {
    this.logger.warn("[JDSU] - New request received.");

    const today = new Date().toLocaleDateString("nl-BE", {
        year: "numeric",
        month: "2-digit",
        day: "2-digit"
      }).split("/");

    const basePath = `${process.cwd()}/public/vendors/x/dsu`;

    try {
      const inputFile =`${basePath}/in/File_X_${today[2]}_${today[1]}_${today[0]}.csv`;
      const outputFile = `${basePath}/out/stock_daily.csv`;

      await this.stockUpdater.readFileWithRetries(inputFile);
      this.logger.log("[JDSU] - File read successfull.");

      await this.stockUpdater.transformFile(inputFile, outputFile);
      this.logger.log("[JDSU] - Uploading file to SFTP server.");

      await this.sftpClient.upload(fse.readFileSync(outputFile), `${this.config.get<string>("cfg.ftp.dgoFtpRemotePath")}/stock_daily.csv`);

      await fse.rm(inputFile);
      await fse.rm(outputFile);

      this.logger.log("[JDSU] - update finished succesfully.");
    } catch (err) {
      throw new InternalServerErrorException(err.message);
    }
  }


Now the operation always keeps hanging at uploading to FTP Server and gives me the error: _put: read ETIMEDOUT but only when the operation is triggered by a producer from nest-schedule.
If I trigger the job manually (REST) then the operation works fine and uploads correctly.
This is the configuration in my App.module.ts for the SFTP connection
SftpModule.forRootAsync({
  inject: [ConfigService],
  imports: [ConfigModule],
  useFactory: async (config: ConfigService) => ({
    host: config.get<string>("cfg.ftp.dgoFtpHost"),
    port: config.get<number>("cfg.ftp.dgoFtpPort"),
    username: config.get<string>("cfg.ftp.dgoFtpUsername"),
    password: config.get<string>("cfg.ftp.dgoFtpPassword")
 })
}, false),

Can anyone help me with this ?
Thanks
